# Excel VBA Replace Messes Up Date formats while Manual Replace works

Tags: vba, excel, date, format

i'm converting a bunch of dates from a automatically generated timestamp into a format excel could understand by removing a "-" inbetween date and time.

using

```
 Sub dateFix()
  Worksheets("INPUT CALC XL BASED").Range("B:B").Replace _
  What:="-", Replacement:="", _
  SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True
 End Sub
```

it will return most of the dates right as DD/MM/AAA, but some will be arbitrarily changed to MM/DD/AAA.

i noticed that the smallest numbers (under 10) tend to be confused.

the input goes somewhat like

```
18/02/2016 - 12:54
10/02/2016 - 17:11
05/02/2016 - 13:13
01/02/2016 - 08:55
```

and it converts like

```
18/02/2016 12:54 (right)
10/02/2016 17:11 (right)
02/05/2016 13:13 (wrong)
02/01/2016 08:55 (wrong)
```

strange is that using Excel's built in Replace, it makes it right.

Comment: can't reproduce. just copied your data and code and it worked just fine. curious, are you a US based user or another country?

Comment: You will also note that the "Right" ones are text and not numbers.  They will be left justified while the "wrong" ones will be right justified and are number masked as data/time.  It has to do with the local settings.

Comment: it is correctly recoginsed as a timestamp, just with the month and day swapped in certain days. 
and @holtz:  i'm from another country

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input is always in the same format and it happens to be a string, you could break it up programmatically and then explicitly reform as a date.

```
For i = 1 to WorksheetFunction.CountA(Rows(1))
  splitdate = Split(Cells(i,2),"-")
  Cells(i,2).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
  Cells(i,2).Value = DateSerial(splitdate(2),splitdate(1),splitdate(0))
Next
```

If its not a string (i.e. some are recognized as date, some as string) you could wrap the Split command in CSTR to force treatment as such.